# How to select first sibling classes of a parent class with css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've tried every possible way with numerous selectors but I cannot seem to find a way to select the class on my website. I've worked out the problem in a JS fiddle here and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ppyjo1bk/

On my website http://wellfixreparaties.nl and I only want to show the first two reviews which are generated by a plugin. This is the structure of the css plugin:

```
<div class='wp-google-reviews'>
   <div class='wp-google-review'></div>
   <div class='wp-google-review'></div>
   <div class='wp-google-review'></div>
   <div class='wp-google-review'></div>
</div>
```

I target the second element class like this:

```
.wp-google-reviews .wp-google-review: nth-of-type(2) {
     background-color: red;
}
```

However, this does not seem to work on my website but it does on the fiddle. I've used !important also and when not using the nth-selected I'm able to change the background of the div's.

Anyone has a idea what's holding me back from using the nth-of-type selector here?

Comment: Is the space before nth-of-type(2) in your example here also present in your website?

Comment: I added `!important` to the rule on your website and it worked fine.

Comment: Seems to me that you CSS is being overridden by the google-review CSS.

Comment: I've got no space in the code and I've used the !important, yet still not working. Also the background was just for example. I'm actually using both display: none and background: red to check whether it's working, but it doesnt show. Also, even if it's getting overwritten shouldn't the Google editor show me that there's a style being overwritten by Google default styles? Because I dont see that style showing up.... very very very weird.

Answer (score 2):

there's another `background-color` property in your web with `!Important` so it's overwritting your property:

```
.wpac, .wpac h1, .wpac h2, .wpac h3, .wpac h4, .wpac h5, .wpac h6, .wpac p, .wpac td, .wpac dl, .wpac tr, .wpac dt, .wpac ol, .wpac form, .wpac select, .wpac option, .wpac pre, **.wpac div**, .wpac table, .wpac th, .wpac tbody, .wpac tfoot, .wpac caption, .wpac thead, .wpac ul, .wpac li, .wpac address, .wpac blockquote, .wpac dd, .wpac fieldset, .wpac li, .wpac strong, .wpac legend, .wpac em, .wpac s, .wpac cite, .wpac span, .wpac input, .wpac sup, .wpac label, .wpac dfn, .wpac object, .wpac big, .wpac q, .wpac font, .wpac samp, .wpac acronym, .wpac small, .wpac img, .wpac strike, .wpac code, .wpac sub, .wpac ins, .wpac textarea, .wpac var, .wpac a, .wpac abbr, .wpac applet, .wpac del, .wpac kbd, .wpac tt, .wpac b, .wpac i, .wpac hr {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

add `!important`to your property and it should work fine as your css sheet is loaded after that one:

```
.wp-google-reviews .wp-google-review: nth-of-type(2) {
         background-color: red !Important;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Seemed to be the !important property. it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the space between the `:` and `nth-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between : and nth in your CSS. Remove that and it will work.

```css
.wp-google-reviews .wp-google-review:nth-of-type(2) {
     background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wp-google-reviews'>
   <div class='wp-google-review'>A</div>
   <div class='wp-google-review'>B</div>
   <div class='wp-google-review'>C</div>
   <div class='wp-google-review'>D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> .wp-google-reviews div:nth-child(2) {     background-color: red;
>       }

the above code selects the second div of class  wp-google-reviews